# Mailgun is showing mail opened when it's actually not

Tags: java, spring, email, webhooks, mailgun

I want to know whether emails are opened by the clients or not (I already have a link along with the email but I want to know if they didn't click the link by opening the email and ignoring it).

Using Mailgun API,

I created webhooks and integrated with Mailgun.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/open-events")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> receiveOpenedEvents(@RequestBody MailGunPayload payload) {
        EventData eventData = payload.getEventData();
        LOGGER.info("Event of type {} received", eventData.getEvent());
        //logic removed
        return new ResponseEntity<Void>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

**But my problem is this webhook is called even when the email is not opened by the client.**

I also tried calling their **Events API** but I get the same thing. (The opened event log when the email is not opened)

This is the piece of code for **Events API.**

```
HttpResponse<String> request = Unirest.get(API_URL + "/events")
                .basicAuth("api", API_KEY)
                .queryString("recipient", user.getEmail())
                .queryString("event", "opened")
                .asString();
        return request.getBody();
```

Below is the screenshot of my webhook from **Mailgun Dashboard.**

[image]

Am I missing something?

PS: The gmail address was used as a client.

Comment: Hello, did you solve this? I have the same issue. I see that some emails are opened right after receiving by possibly some bot or something having user agent of the Edge 12.246 browser

Comment: Hello @onerea, this was a part of POC. I was not able to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be Gmail bot loading images inside an email body that are used to track email open events.

Found out that its user agent is consistent with this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246 Mozilla/5.0
```

Also found a blog post that [confirms this](https://www.gmass.co/blog/false-opens-in-gmail/)

Solved by filtering out webhooks with such a user agent.